# Hibernate annotations work better the "wrong" way around?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I've been looking around the net for a decent answer to this but all I've gotten is confused. I'm struggling with how `@ManyToOne` annotations in hibernate are supposed to work - because `@OneToMany` with `@JoinColumn` seems far superior because hibernate inserts the foreign keys properly instead of me having to assign the child object in java before saving.

Basically as the most simple example I have something like this:

```
Parent Table:  id int,
Child Table :  id int, parentFk int


public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentFk")
    private List<Child> children;

    //setters and getters
}

public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Integer parentFk;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Now if I send some json that maps to a `Parent` class and ask hibernate to save it, it will save everything in the table including the new id of the parent in the parentFk field. However I've been lead to believe that this is actually the wrong way of doing things and that I should be doing `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")` in the `Parent` class instead - and then also having `@ManyToOne` with `@JoinColumn` and a `Parent` object in the `Child` class.

The problem is doing it this way I have to manually set the parent object in the child via java code before hibernate will save the id of the parent in the parentFk field correctly...it just seems like a very long winded of doing something that is already working perfectly for me (albeit I cannot access the parent object from the child).

Moreover I've tried to remove the parentFk field in the child object and use `@ManyToOne` with a parent object reference, but hibernate doesn't seem to like it. Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: You should be mapping objects not id's your `Child` should reference the `Parent` not the id of the parent.

Comment: It also depends on your needs, do you need it to be a bi-directional relationship or uni-relational. However what you have now is wrong as you should be mapping objects and not plain ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using @JsonManagedReference on the @OneToMany mappings and @JsonBackReference on the @ManyToOne

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should be something like this.

```
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Child> children;

    //setters and getters
}

public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentFk")
    private Parent parent;

    //setters and getters
}
```

You should also have an `add(Child child)` method on your parent (and remove) to manage the relation ship. And assuming `Parent` and `Child` are in the same package I would make the `setParent` on the `Child` package protected, i.e no access modifier (`setParent(Parent parent) { this.parent=parent})`.

```
public void add(Child child) {
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}
```

When doing it like this hibernate will be able to execute the right queries.

Comment: Doing it like this makes hibernate insert the row but the foreign key is null...as it stands I don't need to set the child's parent in java for it to insert the fk

Comment: You need to include the cascade else it won't work and you have to manage the dependencies. Like with the `add` method. That method is there for a reason. Also you should store the `Parent` not the `Child` if you now save the `Child` the parent won't get stored.

Comment: That's what I mean - I don't currently need to manage the depencies. Basically my json string has many nested children and I want hibernate to take care of the whole object without me having to set anything manually ( which it currently does when joincolumn is in the parent class ). I have tried including cascade but still nothing. I am always saving the parent object.

Comment: Then you have something wrong else where. Your objects should be about the domain, not about the JSON output.